# Change the thumbnail/preview/top photo for albums in iOS 12

Tags: ios, photos, photos.app

I would like to change the one photo you see for each album when you first open the Photos app.

Answer (score 0):

The thumbnail is determined by the first photo in the album. To change the thumbnail simply drag and photo to the first photo in the album.

Comment: That’s not the case.  I’ve tried that because it would make sense.  Some albums it’s the first photo, some albums it’s the most recent and a couple it’s a random middle one.